# Selecionar o ROW_NUMBER de uma tabela do excel

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel

Hoje eu uso

```
SELECT * FROM [Plan1$]
```

Para selecionar os dados da planilha do Excel, gostaria de saber como faço para selecionar a linha do registro também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `where` para filtrar os registros desejados:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Plan1$]
WHERE [Field_name] = "myFilter"
```